# What is the difference between taurus and bovine?

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, synonymy

What is the difference between taurus and bovine? Both words are from Latin and both words refers to cows or the cow family.

Comment: You mean _taurine_? it's an adjective, like _bovine_. The noun _taurus_ is just the Latin word for 'bull'.

Answer (score 4):

Taurus is a proper name with little synchronic connection to cattle apart from usage of Latin in English for biological nomenclature and astrology, but bovine is an adjective which plainly means "related to cattle". Latin *taurus* probably derives from Greek ταῦρος, and is taken unmodified from Latin into English, whereas bovine is a fully nativized English word borrowed from French which got it from Late Latin *bovinus*.

Comment: Accent correction, ταῦρος.

Comment: Oops, wrong language.

Comment: *ϑawr- is a Mediterranean wander word, also in Semitic.